# Run a separate PowerShell script asynchronously while continuing the current script

Tags: powershell

PowerShell script #1 does the following:

```
Performs FTP ops ending with saving updated remote directory data in a local file
```

The script runs quickly until the remote directory data must be obtained using FTP.  It would be desirable to remove the remote directory data retrieval into a different PowerShell script #2.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549516/run-a-powershell-script-from-another-one) explains launching a script from within a script.  But it seems in this case the first script is suspended while the second script executes.

How can I code script #1 so that script #2 is launched and forgotten and script #1 continues and completes quickly leaving script #2 to finish in the background.

Comment: Use the call operator or Start-Process instead of dot-sourcing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job?view=powershell-5.1) to starts a PowerShell background job. This way the job runs without interacting with the current session and will return immediately while the job is running asynchronously. If you expect receiving a result from the job, you can use `Receive-Job` to get the result.

**Example**

- `Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-Process}`
- `Start-Job -Command "Get-Process"`
- `Start-Job -FilePath "D:\script.ps1"`

You can also use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1) to start another process. You can specify a program executable file or script file, or a file that can be opened by using a program on the computer. When you start process for a non-executable file, the program associated to that file type will run like when you use `Invoke-Item` cmdlet.

**Example**

- `Start-Process PowerShell -Argument "C:\MyScript.ps1"`
- `Start-Process "C:\SomeFile.txt"`

Comment: Perfect, thx.  So simple but if you don't know it, you don't know it.  You answered my question & it works brilliantly as stated above, but I still have an issue. I used this for a build script. When I run the script directly on the build machine, the 1st script launches the 2nd script and the 1st script closes, which is what I wanted.  But when under TFS control, the 2nd script doesn't complete. I think it's because TFS closes the PowerShell context when the 1st script completes.  Is it possible to launch the 2nd script differently in this case to keep it's own PowerShell context open?

Comment: You're welcome. Hmmm, I don't have any idea about how TFS is using those scripts. But also try `Start-Process`.

Comment: I created a batch file and started it from within script #1 using your last example above, running PowerShell from the batch and it worked just fine.  Fixed the TFS issue.  Perfect.  Thx again.

Answer (score -2):

You would have a single script with multiple functions. The script is a standard ps1 script. The use-case here is you are executing blocks of code that do effectively a single task and you get to decide which blocks to execute at which stage of the script execution:

```
Function Get-RemoteDirectory {

   <Insert shorter running operation here>

}

Function Pull-RemoteDirectory {

  Get-RemoteDirectory -Path <Path>

  <Insert longer running operation here>

}

Pull-RemoteDirectory -SourcePath <Path> -DestinationPath <Path>
```

Here I am calling the first function within the second function. You can insert your script logic as you like here. Be careful about [variable scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1). Once your script is ready just save the file and execute as any Powershell script.

NB. You can add param() blocks to your script and/or to your functions. Whatever suits your needs depending on script runtime requirements.

Comment: And how is this asynchronous?!